# Wot no generalists?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

The "Generalist" badge is described as "Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags."  I assume that the top 40 tags are the first forty on the [tag list](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags).

By my reckoning, there are 29 of the top 40 tags for which I've provided answers with a total score of 15 or more; I don't think I've posted any wiki answers. I'm sure several of the other higher-rep users have also done this. But nobody has been awarded the Generalist badge. Why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the official list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/156248):

> Only awarded to anyone after each of the 40 top tags has at least 200 questions

We don't fulfill this criterion yet:
our [40th largest tag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags?page=2&tab=popular) (4th on page 2 of the tag list) only has 119 questions.

Comment: Thanks. That's what one might call "far from obvious". Would be nice if the descriptions on the badges page actually included all the requirements.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know. But the "full description" is oftentimes too long; one learns to visit the list I link after a time. :/

Comment: true but a bit funky/ strange observation to look at the 40th largest tag 1st wrt this metric... looks like youre in for a wait DR. from that list, apparently currently everything from the top (most questions) 26th tag onward has less than 200 questions.